# Cache not refreshing when being called from a asynchrounous function in Spring

Tags: caching, asynchronous, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

I am calling a function which has `CacheEvict` annotation on it. This is being called from a function that is itself executed asynchronously.

It seems that the cache is not being evicted after the function has been executed.

Here is sample code

```
@Async("executor1")
public void function1()
{
    // do something

    anotherFunction("name", 123, 12);

   // do something more

}

@CacheEvict(cacheNames = {"cache1", "cache2", "cache3"}, key = "#testId")
public List<Integer> anotherFunction(String name, int testId, int packageId)
{
  // some code here
}
```

What I want is that entries corresponding to `testId` should be cleared from all the caches.
However, in another call, I can see old entries of `cache1`. `function1` is being called from the controller. Both these functions are present inside the service. Now, Is this configuration correct? If yes, What may be the possible reasons that cache is not being cleared?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that Spring proxies are not reentrant. To implement `Async` and `CacheEvict`, Spring creates a proxy. So, in your example, the call stack will be:

`A -> B$$proxy.function1() -> B.function1() -> B.anotherFunction()`

`B$$proxy` contains the logic for async and eviction. Which won't apply when calling directly `anotherFunction`. In fact, even if you remove the `@Async`, it will still don't work.

A trick you can use is to inject the proxied bean into the class. To delegate to the proxy of the class instead `this`.

```
public class MyClass {    
  private MyClass meWithAProxy;

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    meWithAProxy = applicationContext.getBean(MyClass.class);
  }

  @Async("executor1")
  public void function1() {
    meWithAProxy.anotherFunction("name", 123, 12);
  }

  @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "cache1", key = "#testId")
  public List<Integer> anotherFunction(String name, int testId, int packageId) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

}
```

It works. But there's a catch. If you now call `anotherFunction` directly, it won't work. I consider this to be a Spring bug and will file it as is.

Comment: I had already tried with `this` but it didn't work. I did not know that `this` is different from the bean(my mistake). So now, I have now removed the annotation and am using CacheManager to evict the desired cache. Though I am not sure how correct it is.

Comment: By `this` I meant injecting the proxy. Like in my code example. This works. I tried.